# insert with "error on non existing collection" semantics

Tags: mongodb

The usual behavior in MongoDB is that collections are created upon first document insertion, which is fine for most of the use cases. However, in some cases you want to check if collection previously exists.

It seems [the recommended way of doing this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-validate-existence-of-collection-database/33036) is to rely on `listCollections` to check for collection existence. However, this would involve to do a `listCollections` operation each time a document is inserted, thus duplicating the number of operations done in the database.

Is there any way of running `insert()` (and/or derived methods, such as `insertMany()`, etc.) with "error on non existing collection" semantics or, in general, other alternative to per-insert checking with `listCollections`?

Comment: no as far as I know, you should just store a flag whether collection is create or not somewhere

Comment: maybe keeping that information on the application variable and not check each time? Also look maybe at change streams, in case of collection drop to know it.

Comment: Local cache is unreliable, change stream approach is overcomplicated and potentially require more resources than `listCollections` approach. I also checked if it can be limited on user privileges level, but sadly [insert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#mongodb-authaction-insert) also gives permission to create a collection. Ironically there is a separate action that allows to create collection without rights to insert documents there. I'd suggest to submit a feature request at https://feedback.mongodb.com/